# Integrate ignores Assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I'm asking Mathematica to compute:

```
Integrate[
 Module[{r = {-x, -y, z}}, r/Norm[r]^3],
 {x, -a/2, a/2},
 Assumptions -> Elements[y, Reals] && z > 0 && a > 0]
```

But the result seems to completely ignore my assumptions (I also tried Assuming):

[image: results]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's Element, not Elements. You can tell you've mistyped the command because it's color coded blue.

Comment: I knew it was something incredibly obvious! Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Module[{r = {-x, -y, z}},Integrate[r/Norm[r]^3, {x, -a/2, a/2},Assumptions -> Element [y, Reals] && z > 0 && a > 0]]
(*{0, -((2 a y)/((y^2 + z^2) Sqrt[a^2 + 4 y^2 + 4 z^2])), (2 a z)/((y^2 + z^2) Sqrt[a^2 + 4 y^2 + 4 z^2])}*)
```